# SEO to specify page content category type

Tags: seo, google-search, googlebot, html

I found a web page with its source code having the first line as: `<!-- /electronics/dvd-player -->`

Google search engine is actually treating this special type of comment in a special manner. I want to know what exactly is this, and want to read more about it.

Any suggestions on where to start looking for this?

Comment: Was wondering whether it has anything to do with [schema.org](http://schema.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, I think this has more to do with DMOZ Open Directory project.

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35624
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2012/01/better-page-titles-in-search-results.html

Comment: note: the references you are listing are referring to page titles (which have a heavy impact on SEO). what you where listing in your initial question is a html comment (which does not have an impact on SEO at all)...

Comment: Actually, the page title is where I had found the impact at the first place. In the Google Search Listing page, the title was showing something like "electronics/dvd-player" along with the original page title. Whereas, the original source code of that particular page did not have the "electronics/dvd-player" mentioned anywhere in the title tag. Instead the HTML source code had "<!-- /electronics/dvd-player -->" as the first line.

Comment: If you read the original question, I had said "Google search engine is actually treating this special type of **comment** in a special manner. I want to know what exactly is this, and want to read more about it."

Comment: But you only said "html comment" which I myself mentioned in the question itself. And you also said "no weight regarding SEO" in bold, which is not the case, and confirmed by the two links I already mentioned.

Comment: OK, before re-iterating (just see my first comment to this answer) I stop here.

Comment: That's what I'm saying since the second comment. The html comment is effecting the title of the page and also the SEO.

Answer (score 0):

this is a html comment and has absolutely **no(!)** weight regarding SEO ranking.

see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_comment.asp for details.

Comment: After doing some research, I think this has more to do with DMOZ Open Directory project.